# SQL joins and logic

Tags: c#, sql, sharepoint, join, web-parts

I am working with a SharePoint web part that I am designing in C#. I need to query a SQL Server 2005 database to return the names of machines that are associated with a particular customer, selected by the user.

The problem is that there are different types of machines, and the names themselves are stored in several other tables. Here is the structure as it pertains to this question:

I have a table "customerInfo" which contains the ID and name of each customer. The ID is the primary key.

A table "machineIDs" links the customer IDs to the corresponding machine IDs. The machine ID is the primary key.

I have two tables for two types of machines, "machine1" and "machine2." machine1 contains the name of the machine itself, but machine2 only contains the ID of the type of machine it is. With both of these tables, the machine ID is the primary key.

Then I have a table "specialtyMachine." This table contains the name of the machine and the ID of this type of machine. The primary key here is a type ID, which identifies the type of machine, whereas the machine ID identifies the specific machine.

What I need to do is pull the machine name from machine1 and specialtyMachine, given just the customer ID. I'm not sure whether it's possible to do this with a complex join directly within the query, or if I will need to apply logic in the web part to pull this information together.

I would also like to know how I can think about this in terms of a generic model. I'd like to be able to recognize this and apply it generically in the future, as I'm sure it's a fairly common problem that I just haven't dealt with yet. Thank you.

Comment: Could you add some mote structure/schema of what we need to work wit for such a query?

Comment: I just added some more information to the schema. I think that it now contains all of the pertinent information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your new schema information I'm guessing this is what you want:

```
select *
from customerinfo c
left join machineids mids on c.customerid = mids.customerid
left join machine1 m1 on mids.machineid = m1.machineid
left join spcialtymachine sm on mids.machineid = sm.machineid -- or m1.machineid = sm.machineid
left join machine2 m2 on sm.typeid = m2.typeid
```

note: if you are using this in a stored procedure with an @customerid as a parameter you can add a `where c.customerid = @customerid` to the end.

Comment: This is very nearly it. It does in fact pull all of the rows that I need, and only the ones that I need. However, it does not populate the "sm" (using your designation) fields. This is because the sm.machineid and the mids.machineid are not equivalents. Each customer has a certain number of machines (mids.machineid). Only certain machines have an sm.machineid, which then links them to the specialtymachine table. So the two machineids are different, and this is what has stumped me as to how to return the fields that I need.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your previous queries have already been hugely helpful in both getting me close to this query and understanding how inner joins work. I'll be leaving work in a few minutes but I'll be picking this back up Monday morning. Thanks again.

Comment: ok... does this mean the sm.machineid is a different field in customerinfo (or one of the other tables) or is it just that sm.machineid has a sub-set of all machineids.  if it is a subset this will work fine.  if it is a different external key field I need to know the name.  Also it will show up as multiple rows if someone machineids are in one table and others are in the other table.  then you will need to do some grouping (no worries, it is not hard).

Comment: Yes, sm.machineid and mids.machineid are two different IDs; sm.machineid is not a subset of mids.machineid. As an example, let's say I have a customer whose customer ID is '1001.' In the mids table, they will have, say, three different machine IDs: '5024,' '6708,' and '9699.' For '5204' and '6708,' I can simply pull the corresponding name from machine1.machinename. However, for '9699,' that product's info is in machine2, which does not have a machinename, but instead a different machineid (let's say "192"). This links it to sm, which contains the name I need to use.

Comment: I marked this as the answer. As I said, this returns all of the rows that I need and only the rows that I need; with slight modification based on my schema, I was able to add another LEFT JOIN and pull the additional information from the sm table with just the customer ID. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to union two queries.

```
SELECT c.ID, m1.Name
FROM customerinfo AS c
JOIN machine1 AS m1
ON m1.customerinfoID = c.ID
WHERE c.ID = @customerID

UNION ALL
SELECT c.ID, sm.Name
FROM customerinfo AS c
JOIN machine2 AS m2
ON m2.customerinfoID = c.ID
JOIN specialtyMachine AS sm
ON sm.TypeID = m2.TypeID
WHERE c.ID = @customerID
```

Answer (score 0):

Will your query pass in Customer Name or Customer Id and expect a result?

Is there a crosswalk table between CustomerInfo and Machine1 or does Machine1 have a FK back to CustomerInfo.Id?  Same question for Machine2

Comment: I updated the schema to show the table which links customer IDs to their respective machines. The query will only be passing in the customer ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model sounds a little strange but there is no generic model as far as I can see, what you are talking about is a standard relational database.

To do the query a complex just create the different parts of query in a modular way as shown below (if I'm wrong about where the keys are then the modular way will make it easy to modify for your use.)

First the machine mapping would look something like this:

```
Select m2.mid as mID, m1.name as mName
from specialtyMachine sm
left join machine2 m2 on sm.mid = m2.mid 
left join machine1 m1 on sm.machinename = m1.machinename
```

You can run and test this to see a mapping of machines to ids.

Now we join in the customerinfo:

```
select * 
from customerinfo c
left join 
(
   Select m2.mid as mID, m1.name as mName
   from specialtyMachine sm
   left join machine2 m2 on sm.mid = m2.mid 
   left join machine1 m1 on sm.machinename = m1.machinename
) t on c.mid = t.mid
```

This will work fine (and is good for testing you have the relations right), but not good because the subquery is performed for every row in the outer query, better to "unwind" it like so

```
select * 
from customerinfo c
   left join machine2 m2 on c.mid = m2.mid 
   left joint specialtyMachine sm on m2.mid = sm.mid
   left join machine1 m1 on sm.machinename = m1.machinename
```

caveat :  I did not test this, there might be typos.

Comment: The data model is a little strange, but it is technically 3NF. The business data makes it a little muddled; although each machine has a unique identifier, one type of machine is referred to by a unique name, and the other is referred to by a unique type. For user simplicity, I have to give them these names as opposed to the unique identifiers that our database refers to them by.